# `<` fails for `datetime.timedelta` and `datetime.datetime`

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

following code fails when trying to use `'<'` between a `datetime.timedelta` and `datetime.datetime`

`cert_install_status.get('CertificateExpirationDate') -> 2020-12-31 00:00:00`
`type(cert_install_status.get('CertificateExpirationDate')) -> <class 'datetime.datetime'>`

failing code,

```
if (cert_install_status.get('CertificateExpirationDate') - datetime.now()) < (datetime.today() + timedelta(365)):
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.timedelta' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

question: what can I do to compare two objects

Comment: That comparison doesn't make sense. Can you explain, in English, what you were trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this bit:

```
cert_install_status.get('CertificateExpirationDate')
```

Is supposed to return a datetime, then the error is because datetime - datetime gives a timedelta, and date + timedelta gives a datetime.

```
# This is datetime - datetime = timedelta
cert_install_status.get('CertificateExpirationDate') - datetime.now()

# This is datetime + timedelta = datetime
datetime.today() + timedelta(365)
```

The < operator works between two datetimes or between two timedeltas, but not a mix!